# Roundup in access 2007-2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a requirement to roundup to 2dp in Access 2007 and have tried using the answers from a similar query on this forum but have found bugs in all but one.  Does anyone have a tested VB script / function that works taking in a value that may be 14 decimal places long and outputs to 2 dp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed:

```vb
' Common constants.
'
' Base values.
Public Const Base2      As Double = 2
Public Const Base10     As Double = 10

' Enums.
'
Public Enum rmRoundingMethod
    Down = -1
    Midpoint = 0
    Up = 1
End Enum


' Rounds Value up with count of decimals as specified with parameter NumDigitsAfterDecimal.
'
' Rounds to integer if NumDigitsAfterDecimal is zero.
'
' Optionally, rounds negative values away from zero.
'
' Uses CDec() to prevent bit errors of reals.
'
' Execution time is about 0.5µs for rounding to integer,
' else about 1µs.
'
' 2018-02-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RoundUp( _
    ByVal Value As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal NumDigitsAfterDecimal As Long, _
    Optional ByVal RoundingAwayFromZero As Boolean) _
    As Variant

    Dim Scaling     As Variant
    Dim ScaledValue As Variant
    Dim ReturnValue As Variant

    ' Only round if Value is numeric and ReturnValue can be different from zero.
    If Not IsNumeric(Value) Then
        ' Nothing to do.
        ReturnValue = Null
    ElseIf Value = 0 Then
        ' Nothing to round.
        ' Return Value as is.
        ReturnValue = Value
    Else
        If NumDigitsAfterDecimal <> 0 Then
            Scaling = CDec(Base10 ^ NumDigitsAfterDecimal)
        Else
            Scaling = 1
        End If
        If Scaling = 0 Then
            ' A very large value for NumDigitsAfterDecimal has minimized scaling.
            ' Return Value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        ElseIf RoundingAwayFromZero = False Or Value > 0 Then
            ' Round numeric value up.
            If Scaling = 1 Then
                ' Integer rounding.
                ReturnValue = -Int(-Value)
            Else
                ' First try with conversion to Decimal to avoid bit errors for some reals like 32.675.
                On Error Resume Next
                ScaledValue = -Int(CDec(-Value) * Scaling)
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Decimal overflow.
                    ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                    ScaledValue = -Int(-Value * Scaling)
                    ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' Round absolute value up.
            If Scaling = 1 Then
                ' Integer rounding.
                ReturnValue = Int(Value)
            Else
                ' First try with conversion to Decimal to avoid bit errors for some reals like 32.675.
                On Error Resume Next
                ScaledValue = Int(CDec(Value) * Scaling)
                ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Decimal overflow.
                    ' Round Value without conversion to Decimal.
                    ScaledValue = Int(Value * Scaling)
                    ReturnValue = ScaledValue / Scaling
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            ' Rounding failed because values are near one of the boundaries of type Double.
            ' Return value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        End If
    End If

    RoundUp = ReturnValue

End Function
```

**Example**:

```vb
Value14 = CDec("12345.00000000000001")
Value02 = RoundUp(Value14, 2) 
Value02 -> 12345.01
```

You may also study my article on the subject of *rounding with extreme precision*:

[Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/20299/Rounding-values-up-down-by-4-5-or-to-significant-figures.html)

*(If you don't have an account, browse for the link: Read the full article)*

Full code is also on **GitHub**: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round)

Comment: Hi, I'm passing this function values in the format Roundup(0.1234,2) and its setting scaling to zero therefore returning the value without rounding.  I'm not sure why, do i need to pass it the value as text?

Comment: Scaling? Please post your full code (appended to your question).

Comment: I'm using your code with Roundup(0.1234,2)   This if sets scaling to 0 everytime:                          If NumDigitsAfterDecimal <> 0 Then
            Scaling = CDec(Base10 ^ NumDigitsAfterDecimal)

Comment: That returns `0.13`.

Comment: - assuming dot is the decimal separator. Sounds like you use comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: I'm calling the function as above roundup(0.1234,2) and like i say the Scaling variable gets set to 0 so exits the function without doing anything...  NumDigitsAfterDecimal = 2 when i step through, but the result of this:  Scaling = CDec(Base10 ^ NumDigitsAfterDecimal) = 0

Comment: Can i ask what this is calculated as on your version: Scaling = CDec(Base10 ^ NumDigitsAfterDecimal) where NumDigitsAfterDecimal = 2

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I forgot the common constants and enum. See edited answer, please. Also, always include `Option Explicit` in your module; that would have caught the missing constant at once.